# onClick function is running on another event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have been playing around with react. Have two event listeners the input which listens onChange and the button which should push the value to the array when its clicked.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
let arr = [];
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {text: 'default'}
  }
  update( e ) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  }
  add ( value ) {
    arr.push(value)
    console.log(arr)
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.text}</h1> 
      <input onChange={this.update.bind(this)}/>
      <button onClick={this.add(this.state.text)}>Save</button>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

The problem that the add function is running on change. Can't really get why.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `onChange()` triggers `update()`
2. `update()` calls `this.setState()` which changes state.
3. A state change causes `render()` to be invoked to re-render according to new state.
4. Rendering `<button onClick={this.add(this.state.text)}>Save</button>` invokes `add()` every time `render()` runs.

In order to *defer* invoking `add()`, you can define a function which gets triggered by the `click` event, as was shown in another answer. Alternatively, you can achieve the same functionality by adding a class method which encapsulates the trigger functionality:

```
addText() {
  this.add(this.state.text)
}
render() { 
   …
   <button onClick={this.addText.bind(this)}>Save</button>
```

This may or may not work for you, but in the context of the example, given, this would work.

Comment: But how does one escape that, what are the best practices ?

Comment: I added an example of how to defer the call to add() until the event is triggered. Best practices? This approach is more explicit, but also more specific. The anonymous function used in the other answer would be fine, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<button onClick={this.add(this.state.text)}>Save</button>` 
To `<button onClick={() => this.add(this.state.text)}>Save</button>`

In your variant function add firing when component is rendering, and when you call `setState` with onChange of input you call this re-render.

Comment: I wrote little description :)
In my variant `add` will call just with `onClick`, but in yours it will call with `render`

Comment: Yes, but is was wondering about your version. So adding arrow function somehow escapes the render function ?

Comment: Yes... it _defines_ a function which will call `add()` when the `onClick()` is triggered, but does not invoke `add()` at the time `render()` is run.

Comment: This function will work as you want if you will not pass parameter to it, just `onClick={this.add}`. Construction `this.add` give ref to function `add`, but `this.add()` call this function. Check logs in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82053/)

So you just need to wrap it, in another function to defend from firing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `add(this.state.text)` is called whenever `render()` is called. To avoid this, you do not need to send the state as parameter, all you need to do is

`<button onClick={this.add}>Save</button`

or if you want to send a parameter you should bind it

`<button onClick={this.add.bind(this, this.state.text)}>Save</button>`